# how do i migrate Azure storage account from classic to ARM

Tags: azure

i have created a storage account and have a few VM's and blobs. It is supposed to be a classic account.
i want to migrate or convert the storage account to ARM or new version. what is the process to do so?
i have tried to move the contents of one resource manager to a different one, but i didn't get the option to move from classic to ARM
[image]
thanks

Comment: please if one of the answers solved the problem for you, don't forget to accept it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

The whole process of moving ASM to ARM resources can be found here.

[Migrate IaaS resources from classic to Azure Resource Manager by using Azure PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps)

To migrate a Storage Account, all you need is to execute the following PS Cmdlets:

```
ps:> $storageAccountName = "myStorageAccount"
ps:> Move-AzureStorageAccount -Validate -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName
ps:> Move-AzureStorageAccount -Prepare -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName
ps:> Move-AzureStorageAccount -Commit -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName
```

If you want to abort the process (before commit), just use:

```
Move-AzureStorageAccount -Abort -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName
```

Comment: This was the shortest explanation on the nest for this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> i want to migrate or convert the storage account to ARM or new
>   version.

In Azure, we **can't** convert the storage account from ASM to ARM, but we **can** migrate it.

Are you want to move VMs and storage account to ARM module? If yes, we can use follow script to move those:

move **VMs** to ARM module(this VM create without network, behind cloud service):

```
Login-AzureRmAccount  #login Azure Account ARM module
Get-AzureRMSubscription | Sort SubscriptionName | Select SubscriptionName
Select-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "My Azure Subscription"
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.ClassicInfrastructureMigrate
Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.ClassicInfrastructureMigrate


Add-AzureAccount     #login Azure Account ASM module
Get-AzureSubscription | Sort SubscriptionName | Select SubscriptionName
Select-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName "My Azure Subscription"
Get-AzureService | ft Servicename
$serviceName = "jasonvm333"
$deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName
$deploymentName = $deployment.DeploymentName


$validate = Move-AzureService -Validate -ServiceName $serviceName -DeploymentName $deploymentName -CreateNewVirtualNetwork
$validate.ValidationMessages

Move-AzureService -Prepare -ServiceName $serviceName -DeploymentName $deploymentName -CreateNewVirtualNetwork
Move-AzureService -Commit -ServiceName $serviceName -DeploymentName $deploymentName
```

After VMs move complete, then use PowerShell to move **Storage Account** to ARM module:

```
$storageAccountName = "jasontest333"
Move-AzureStorageAccount -Prepare -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName
Move-AzureStorageAccount -Commit -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName
```

More information about move IaaS resources to ARM module, like migrate the VMs to a platform-created virtual network or migrate to an existing virtual network in the Resource Manager deployment model, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps).

Comment: For now, we can't use azure portal to move classic to ARM, we can use Azure PowerShell to achieve this. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `@Stevie W` is correct, there is an option in the Storage Account (Classic) blade that offers *Migrate to ARM*. Clicking it offers buttons for Validation, Prepare, and Commit.

[image: Azure Migrate to ARM]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, however this thread comes up when searching for migrating classic storage to ARM so thought I'd provide an update.

Since the last comment on here, the Azure Portal has been update to allow running the migration process within the blades.   This has worked for a test account, and seems to just apply the 3 powershell commands that have already been noted by Bruno

[Azure Storage Blade - "Migrate To ARM" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7exUi.png)